# tsql merge slows down

Tags: database, t-sql, indexing

TSql merge instruction slows down for some reason.

I merge data batch after batch with batch size equal to 10000 records and i see that from one batch to another merging takes longer and longer.

Here is the merge instruction:

```
MERGE [dbo].[SResult] AS target
            USING [dbo].[SResultTemp] AS source 
            ON (target.QSId = source.QSId 
                and target.ResultId = source.ResultId 
                and target.EngineId = source.EngineId)  
            WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT 
                (QSId, ResultId, EngineId, Position) 
            values 
                (source.QSId, source.ResultId, source.EngineId, source.Position);
```

the source table declared like this

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SResultTemp](
        [QSId] int not null,
        [ResultId] int not null,
        [EngineId] int not null,
        [Position] int not null,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_SResultTemp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(
            [QSId], [ResultId], [EngineId], [Position] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

the target is the same but it has additional field SResultId as a primary key and another set of indexes:

PK_SResult - primary

IX_SResult_QSId_ResultId - nonunique, nonclustered

IX_SResult_EngineId - nonunique, nonclustered

UX_SResult_EngineId_QSId_Position - unique, non clustered

and here is what i see in the log:

```
    Results Upload: SResult took 00:00:01.0008344 
    Results Upload: SResult took 00:00:18.1046734
    Results Upload: SResult took 00:00:17.9797846
    Results Upload: SResult took 00:00:27.7828817
    Results Upload: SResult took 00:01:30.4140091
    Results Upload: SResult took 00:03:17.6433416
    Results Upload: SResult took 00:03:21.3761251
    Results Upload: SResult took 00:06:07.2555342
    Results Upload: SResult took 00:06:56.2423653
    Results Upload: SResult took 00:06:57.1729179
    Results Upload: SResult took 00:07:09.7221083
```

Also, I work with multiple tables, so for the other tables there is no regularity like this. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: To be fair your PK is a bit out of hand.

Comment: As the PK gets fragments insert speed will degrade (and a lot faster than you think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indexes fragment insert speed degrades.
And as you see can degrade rapidly.
If you can insert in the order of PK then that will reduce fragmentation.
Pad the indexes will slow down the fragmentation.
Can you drop all non clustered indexed then rebuild after the inserts are complete?

Is SResultId an Identity?

Why that index design?
You have a unique constraint that is not the same as the PK on SResultTemp.

Indexes speed up select but they slow down insert and update.
An index on the join will help but right now that index is split.

My advice is to break it down to only indexes that are required for uniqueness and test.

Comment: in fact, it appears that unique index was killing the performance. If i disable it, no degradation occurs anymore. 
So the question is how to grant the uniqueness without using unique index.

Comment: Don't insert duplicates.

Comment: Don't insert duplicates is a great idea, but sometimes someone could break something. once it happened, so we had to create this index to prevent issues like this.
Well, the solution was pretty simple:
it was noticed that degradation occurs only on very specific data: 
all bathes have the same EngineId and QSId (which was unique for the series of batches. in the other words no other process could create any record with the same EngineId).
So in fact only Position index worked. 
So index fields shuffling helped: new unique index UX_SResult_EngineId_Position_QSId gives absolutely no degradation

Answer (score 1):

Of course it takes longer what else would you expect with a clusterd PK that has four fields? You are continually reordering all the records in your table during the merge.

Comment: the PK seems to be fine - the Unique index was killing the performance

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. increasing the index and the resulting maintainance work as more and more rows are added
2. the ON-CLAUSE

   ```
   ON (target.QSId = source.QSId 
       and target.ResultId = source.ResultId 
       and target.EngineId = source.EngineId)
   ```

causes increased need for checks in the target as more and more rows are present that need to be compared.

Getting rid of the index will slow down the check of the ON-clause extremely. We have a conflict of interest here.

Comment: Yes, but the issue is that i have seven tables like this with complicated pk. And none of them shows merge degradation at all.

Comment: @user2703790 I am very surprised that you have heavily indexes tables that you are seeing no degradation in merge.  Please post a sample.

Comment: When unique index is down, clause works on two another indexes and no degradation occurs.